# How can I store foreign Keys as arrays in laravel?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel

I have 3 models:

- `Book`
- `Author`
- `Owner`

`Book` has:

- `id`
- `name`
- `photo`
- `author_id`
- `owner_id`
- `is_available`

`Author` has:

- `id`
- `name`
- `photo`

`Owner` has:

- `id`
- `name`
- `photo`
- `book_id`

A book can have multiple `Authors` and `Owners`.

How can I store more single id in `author_id` and `owner_id`?

Comment: Why not use a common many to many relationship? How do you currently define the relations? Manually, or through Eloquent?

Comment: You don't, you use a Many To Many relationship (using a pivot table), it is basic programming/db normalization, not Laravel. Check this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the author has many books, and the book have many authors, than it’s a many to many relationship and you will need intermediate tables author_book and owner_book. In order to be able to define many author ids for one a book and many books for one author.
Check the Laravel doc here for implementation details https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Good luck.

Comment: To be precise, following the Laravel standards naming conventions, you will need `author_book` and `book_owner`, not `owner_book`